# How to change the color of a icon among multiple icons one at a time using click event in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, onclick, click, angular-directive

I have an angular application In that I have added 6 icons .My requirement is when I click on any button the particular icon color should changed from gray red color, and when I click on other icon the other icon changed to red color and previous color changed button should changed to gray color.

and my angular code is:

**.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
<span class="icon-number"></span><i class="smiley  icon-face-1"></i>
        <span class="icon-number"></span><i class="smiley  icon-face-2"></i>
        <span class="icon-number"></span><i class="smiley  icon-face-3"></i>
        <span class="icon-number"></span><i class="smiley  icon-4"></i>
        <span class="icon-number"></span><i class="smiley icon-face-5"></i>
        <span class="icon-number"></span><i class="smiley icon-face-6"></i>
</div>
```

So Can any one help me how to change the color of particular icon using click event in angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="container">
    <button *ngFor="let btn of btnArr" type="button" class="buttonstyle"
        [style.background-color]="selectedButton === btn ? '#FF0000' : 'grey'" (click)="selectedButton = btn">
        {{btn}}
    </button>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <i (click)="selectedIcon = icon.id" class="smiley" [ngClass]="icon.class"
        [style.color]="selectedIcon === icon.id ? '#FF0000' : '#000000'" *ngFor="let icon of iconsArr"></i>
</div>
```

In component ts file

```
btnArr = ["BUTTON-1", "BUTTON-2", "BUTTON-3", "BUTTON-4", "BUTTON-5", "BUTTON-6"];
selectedButton = "";

iconsArr = [
        { id: 1, class: "icon-face-1" },
        { id: 2, class: "icon-face-2" },
        { id: 3, class: "icon-face-3" },
        { id: 4, class: "icon-face-4" },
        { id: 5, class: "icon-face-5" },
        { id: 6, class: "icon-face-6" }
    ];
    selectedIcon = 0;
```

Comment: thanks @zainhassan , so if have icons in place of buttons like <span class="icon-number"></span><i class="smiley-icon icon icon-face-1"></i> like this I have 6 icons So how  i can change the color of icon if I click the icon, then it would be helpful for me

Comment: Share full code how you want to display icons. You can use stackblitz to create example

Comment: I edited the code Please refer.

Comment: Thanks@zainhassan, If you notice span tag before i tag used to write the numbers like .icon-number{
    position: relative;
    left: 22px;
    top: 20px;
  }
 .icon-number:after{
    content: counter(number);
    counter-increment: number;
  }   So when I click on icon this particular number should be bold

Answer (score 0):

In Component.ts File Take on a variable and name it as
**currentButton=''**

Also, make on function on .ts side will set the current button

```
SetCurrentButton(buttonValue:string){
this.currentButton=buttonValue;
}
```

Now From Html In Your Button Code do Below Change

```
<div class="container">

 <button type="button" class="buttonstyle" (click)="SetCurrentButton(btn1)" [ngStyle]="{'color':currentButton === 'btn1' ? 'red' : '' }">
          BUTTON-1
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="buttonstyle" (click)="SetCurrentButton(btn2)" [ngStyle]="{'color':currentButton === 'btn2' ? 'red' : '' }">
          BUTTON-2
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="buttonstyle" (click)="SetCurrentButton(btn3)" [ngStyle]="{'color':currentButton === 'btn3' ? 'red' : '' }">
          BUTTON-3
        </button>
 <button type="button" class="buttonstyle" (click)="SetCurrentButton(btn4)" [ngStyle]="{'color':currentButton === 'btn4' ? 'red' : '' }">
          BUTTON-4
        </button>
 <button type="button" class="buttonstyle" (click)="SetCurrentButton(btn5)" [ngStyle]="{'color':currentButton === 'btn5' ? 'red' : '' }">
          BUTTON-5
        </button>
<button type="button" class="buttonstyle" (click)="SetCurrentButton(btn6)" [ngStyle]="{'color':currentButton === 'btn6' ? 'red' : '' }">
          BUTTON-6
        </button>
</div>
```